# C++ Network program runs but give no output

Tags: c++, network-programming

My simple program gives no errors through the compiler and runs fine but it does not give the output it is supposed too until someone is connected. I have done a good bit of research and editing but can not figure it out.Also how do I let more than one person connect? Any help to get this to work would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!! Code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char msg[20];

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Made it to main!";

    int listener_d = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in name;
    name.sin_family = PF_INET;
    name.sin_port = (in_port_t)htons(30000);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind (listener_d, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name)) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Can't bind the port!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The port has been bound.";
    }

    listen(listener_d, 10);
    cout << "Waiting for connection...";

    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
        unsigned int address_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        int connect_d = accept(listener_d, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &address_size);
        cin >> msg;

        send(connect_d, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "but it does not give the output it is supposed too" What is the output it is supposed to give?

Comment: I just compiled it [on liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/40ZzEI$0) and it gave output.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try flushing the output.

```
std::cout << "Waiting for connection..." << std::flush;
```

Comment: As soon as you read from `cin >> msg;` shouldn't `cout` get flushed?

Comment: @Jesse: IIRC there's a setting for that.  But notice nothing gets read from `cin` until the socket connects.  The program happily waits on the `accept()` call, `cin` isn't used, and `cout` isn't flushed.

Comment: +1 the OP just edited the question to say `until someone is connected`.

Comment: Also how do I let more than one person connect?

Comment: @ExZiMeC0PP3R: That "How do I let more than one person connect?" looks like a new question.

Comment: @ExZiMeC0PP3R Just accept the answer, there is no need to say thank - *Other than social standars, blah*